# Excel formula to compare single value in one cell with multiple values in other cell

Tags: excel, compare, formula

I have a value in Column A, which I wnat to compare with multiple values of corresponding cell column B and put the answer in column C. Say it searching in column B for values which are less than or equal to 12 and put the answer in same order in column C.

```
Column A ####  Column B        #### Column C

12       ####  10,12,13,14     #### Yes, Yes, No, No

101      ####  101,102,103,104 #### Yes, No, No, No
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for it to return in Column A?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as you described in your problem, that the cells in Column `B` and `C` are strings, separated by commas, then the easiest way is to do this using a user-defined function (called `StringComp`) in VBA.

The function takes two arguments, one for the list of comma separated numbers in `Column B`, and the second points to the cell with the number you wish to use as a comparison to your list, `Column A`.

I think this can be done using array functions, but the VBA solution is much simpler.

After first copying and pasting the below VBA into your workbook VBA Module, for your example above, assuming your data starts from `Row 1`, you would use the `StringComp` function by putting `=StringComp(B1,A1)` in cell `C1`, and this will return `Yes,Yes,No,No`, as per your example.

```
Public Function StringComp(a As Variant, b As Variant) As String
Dim strOUT, strOUT_temp, strArray() As String
Dim intCount As Integer


strArray = Split(a.Text, ",")

For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
If (Val(strArray(intCount)) <= Val(b)) Then
    strOUT_temp = "Yes"
Else
    strOUT_temp = "No"
End If
If (intCount = LBound(strArray)) Then
     strOUT = strOUT_temp
Else
     strOUT = strOUT & "," & strOUT_temp
End If
Next

StringComp = strOUT

End Function
```

Comment: What was the answer then? Or where was the answer located?